# What JIT compilers does CLR support

Tags: clr, jit

I came across this quote:

> "The .NET Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR) supplies at least one JIT
>   compiler for every NET-supported
>   computer architecture, so the same set
>   of CIL can be JIT-compiled and run on
>   different architectures."

I've looked around but can't find a definitive list of the JIT compilers supported by CLR?

Comment: Did they mean x86, (whatever the 64bit for x86 is), IA64, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly there is one JIT compiler for every processor architecture the CLR runs on.  In particular

- x86
- amd64
- ia64

Less sure about the following.

- PowerPC (XBox360)
- ARM (Mobile devices)

Comment: PowerPC for XBox 360 and ARM for PocketPC, at a guess?

Comment: @Jon, forgot about those. I'm not familiar with the particulars of them but logically they have to exist.

Comment: PPC and ARM don't necessarily exist. In case of Xbox 360, it's not possible to have JIT technically (no code can be generated at runtime). The same on some mobile platforms (e.g. iPhone, even if it's not related to .NET). So on those platforms, it's likely that .NET code uses traditional virtual machine of full "ahead of time" compilation (no JIT at runtime).

Comment: @NeARAZ: what makes you say that the Xbox 360 can't generate code at runtime? Just because user-level code isn't allowed to do so, doesn't mean that Microsoft can't create a JIT for that platform.

Comment: @saua, NeARAZ I'm fairly certain it does JIT on the XBox but I don't know 100% for sure.